# Windows 8.1 sometimes fails to start

Tags: windows-8.1, boot, windows-8.1-upgrade

Since I upgraded my computer from Windows 8 to 8.1, I noticed some strange behavior: Whenever I try to start it or resume (after hibernate), I can not do it at the first time. 
I see the black screen with the Starting Windows text, and the "circle of dots" moving that represent the loading progress. But, at a certain moment, that circle becomes stalled and computer does nothing anymore.

I have to power off by brute force, using the computer's physical power button, and useit again to power on. After that it boots up normally.

Side note: sometimes when I am on Windows the computer enters on a sleep state. And when I use battery and its level becomes low, Windows enters in an unrecoverable sleep state. I have to power off and lose all my work.

The computer is Asus X61Z laptop, having an AMD Athlon X64 processor and the Windows is also 64 bit.

Comment: Hibernation problems are caused by driver problems have you updated to a windows 8.1 supported driver

Comment: Is "fast boot" on or off ? I would recommend switching off.